# sorting with drag & drop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my app i have a list of items which is showing in the view and we can do sorting with drag & drop those items, so when I do the drag & drop I will update the sequence in the table

params we are getting

```
{"item"=>{"33194"=>"1", "30936"=>"2"}}
```

here key is the item_id and value is the sequence, so in the controller i will update it like

```
params[:item].each do |item|
  new_item = Item.find(item[0].to_i)
  new_item.sequence_no = item[1].to_i
  new_item.save
end
```

But here the issue is if we have more items then it will take so much of time to update each and every item then i tried to run this same query with direct execution

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

it reduces the time bit.Is there any other way to achieve this with any additional gem?